# Show default Bluetooth pairing request dialog

Tags: android, bluetooth, dialog, broadcastreceiver, pairing

I am really struggling with this problem and I cannot find a way to do it. I need to show the default dialogs from Android when pairing with a Bluetooth device.

Right now I achieved to pair them programmatically with a quite easy method but it only works from API 19. And I need this to be done from API 18.

Right now, when I connect to a device in my app I get the notification asking to pair a device, but it doesn't show the dialog to do so. If I want it, I have to expand the notifications in the device and click in the pair request notification.

Is there any method which I could call, for example when I receive the notification in my broadcast receiver, to show me the default pairing request dialog? And after the user accepts the pairing and inputs the PIN just do the process to pair, dismiss it and keep using the app?

Your help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm interested if there is a solution to this problem, as well